# Разница для пользователя между LL и LR парсерами

Tags: парсер, синтаксический-анализ

В чем будет заключаться разница для пользователя между LL и LR парсерами, при синтаксическом анализе исходных кодов программ, при учете, что и тот и другой могут успешно проанализировать грамматику языка этих самых программ?
Я пытался найти какой-нибудь удобоваримый ответ, но, честно говоря, не знаю где искать. Я понимаю разницу между этими видами парсеров, но не совсем понимаю в чем различие именно для пользователя.
[Вот здесь](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/07/ll-and-lr-parsing-demystified.html) есть пример вывода

LL: `object '{' pairs(1) pair STRING ':' value(1) STRING pairs_tail(2) '}'`

И LR: `'{' STRING ':' STRING value(1) pair pairs_tail(2) pairs(1) '}' object`

Для потока токенов: `{ STRING : STRING }`

Собственно, это и есть весь ответ на вопрос или я что-то упустил?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то вот в таком: `if (a) if(b) doX(); else doY();` - один из них распарсит так `if (a) { if(b) doX(); else doY(); }`, а другой так: `if (a) { if(b) doX(); } else doY();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два ответа. Первый касается сложности подготовки грамматики.

LL-анализаторы не умеют разбирать леворекурсивные правила.

LR-грамматика может содержать правила, где `expression` выражается через определение, самым левым нетерминалом в которым также является `expression`.

```
expression ::= expression + expression
             | expression - expression
             | expression * expression
             | expression / expression
             | term
             ;
```

LL-анализаторы на этом правиле будут *зависать*. Чтобы избежать зависания, требуется ручное преобразование, тогда получится избавиться от левой рекурсии.

```
expression ::= term tail
             ;

tail       ::= + expression
             | - expression
             | * expression
             | / expression
             |
             ;
```

Такие преобразования тривиальны, но трудоёмки. Они незаметны программисту, который пользуется языком программирования, поэтому о разнице здесь говорить не приходится.

То, что может заметить программист, это разница в языках, которые допускает грамматика.

Поэтому второй ответ — про разницу в языках, которую не убрать никакими преобразованиями.

Во-первых, для LL-грамматик k имеет значение. Бывают языки, которые можно описать грамматикой LL(k + 1), но нельзя LL(k). Для LR грамматик все языки можно привести к LR(1).

Пример LL(k) языка при k > 1. Предположим, в нашем языке мы можем записывать списки чисел:

```
foo = 123 34 564 234 23 354
```

Но язык также позволяет работать с двухмерным и и трёхмерными векторами. Чтобы обозначить такой вектор, мы должны записать суффикс `vec`за последним числом.

```
point2d = 100 200 vec
point3d = 50 40 30 vec
```

Вектор `point2d` сможет разобрать грамматика LL(3), а `point3d` — грамматика LL(4). Почему? Потому что надо прочитать 3 или 4 токена, чтобы понять, с чем мы работаем — со списком произвольной длины или вектором длины 2 или 3.

Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640800/1051621) ответ на вопрос, там ссылка на книгу, где разобраны подобные примеры.

Теперь пример языка, который сможет разобрать грамматика LR(1), но не сможет LL(k).

Предположим, в нашем языке мы можем записывать приход и доход товаров на склад.

```
balance = I I I I I O O O
```

Каждый `I` означает приход, а каждый `O` — расход. Согласен, странный способ записи, но все нестранные задачи вполне могут быть записаны с помощью грамматики LL(1).

Главное правило: количество расходов `O` может быть меньше, чем количество приходов `I`, или равно ему, но не может быть больше. Отрицательных остатков на складе не бывает.

LR(1) грамматика для такого синтаксиса выглядит так:

```
balance ::= I balance
          | pair
          ;

pair    ::= I pair O
          |
          ;
```

А вот LL(k) грамматики для него нет ни при каком k.

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811523/1051621) ответ, где приведён похожий пример.

В действительности, не обязательно проверять корректность конструкций с помощью грамматики. Мы можем сделать LL(1), которая прочитает все I и все O, а потом руками проверить, что количество I больше или равно количеству O.

Кроме того, инструкции современных языков программирования описываются грамматикой LL(1).

Выбор между LL и LR зачастую объясняется тем, что LL(1) грамматику можно закодировать вручную, а для LR обычно требуется инструментальное средство наподобие **yacc**. **yacc** требует освоения и опыта, но он позволяет ускорить работу над компилятором, если вы регулярно расширяете язык.